# psql : connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tags: postgresql

I have installed postgresql and done all the setup and created db and tables yesterday but today morning I got sudden this error

I have also uninstalled and installed postgresql but still same error. And also I have observed that when installed freshly it is working fine but once I shutdown or restart my system I'm getting the below error.

```
 psql:
 could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have tried all the solutions given in all the mediums but I'm not able to resolve the issue so I'm posting this question again with my outputs.

The status of postgresql

```
**sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql status**

postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Wed 2019-10-30 11:40:39 IST; 5min ago
Process: 7666 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 7666 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Tasks: 0
Memory: 0B
  CPU: 0
CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service
```

When I run the pg_lsclusters

```
**pg_lsclusters**

Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
11  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/11/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log

 **dpkg -l | grep postgres**

ii  pgdg-keyring                                2018.2                                       all          keyring for apt.postgresql.org
ii  postgresql                                  11+207.pgdg16.04+1                           all          object-relational SQL database (supported version)
ii  postgresql-11                               11.5-3.pgdg16.04+1                           amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 11 server
ii  postgresql-client-11                        11.5-3.pgdg16.04+1                           amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 11
ii  postgresql-client-common                    207.pgdg16.04+1                              all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common                           207.pgdg16.04+1                              all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
ii  postgresql-contrib                          11+207.pgdg16.04+1                           all          additional facilities for PostgreSQL (supported version)
```

I even tried to restart the postgres still same issue.

```
 **sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql status**
```

Comment: Check out these similar articles : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182189/how-do-i-access-postgres-when-i-get-an-error-about-var-run-postgresql-s-pgsql ,  https://askubuntu.com/questions/50621/cannot-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432

Comment: What is the setting of `port` and `unix_socket_directories` in `postgresql.conf`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' & port = 5432

Comment: @HarshBafna I have tried all the solutions none working.

Comment: Is the socket file present? Is PostgreSQL running? Is there anything in the PostgreSQL log file?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe do we need to set environment variables in ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: @HarshBafna do we need to set environment variables in ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. Why don't you try to answer the question the error message very helpfully asks you?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this error message, and this is how I resolved it.

In the log file at `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-13-main.log`, these lines were present:

```
2021-09-15 08:26:04.936 UTC [46258] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_messages": "en_US.UTF-8"
2021-09-15 08:26:04.936 UTC [46258] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_monetary": "en_US.UTF-8"
2021-09-15 08:26:04.937 UTC [46258] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_numeric": "en_US.UTF-8"
2021-09-15 08:26:04.937 UTC [46258] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_time": "en_US.UTF-8"
2021-09-15 08:26:04.937 UTC [46258] FATAL:  configuration file "/etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf" contains errors
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

This is caused by missing locales, with these possible fixes:

1. `localedef` allegedly fixes this according but I had no luck with this.

   ```
   localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
   ```
2. change postgresql.conf and use a locale that does exist (en_GB in my case)

   ```
   lc_messages = 'en_GB.UTF-8'          # locale for system error message strings
   lc_monetary = 'en_GB.UTF-8'          # locale for monetary formatting
   lc_numeric = 'en_GB.UTF-8'           # locale for number formatting
   lc_time = 'en_GB.UTF-8'              # locale for time formatting
   ```
3. post settings

   ```
   port = 5432              # (change requires restart)
   ```

Port was wrong on my PostgreSQL 13 default config (was 5433) and required a change back to the default 5432. I presume this was a result of upgrading from v11 so it gave it a new port number.

After these changes, PostgreSQL needs to restart and it should now function correctly without errors in the log, and the `psql` command working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`sudo -u postgres -i`

And then:

`initdb --locale $LANG -E UTF8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data/'`

`exit`

This has worked for me so far